# Error Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException

Tags: sharepoint-online

My SharePoint library is generating this error and does not read my SharePoint list.

[image]

```
ServerLibraryVersion = 'context.ServerLibraryVersion' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException'
```

Someone could tell me what I can do in this case

Comment: Is there a specific problem with reading a list in your site collection, or are you just curious as to why the debugger is showing these exceptions in the screen cap above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property is available only after the first ExecuteQuery method is executed on your context object see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext.serverversion.aspx
ie once you do `context.ExecuteQuery();` the property will be available.